# How to get file suffix in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to get the suffix(.txt,.png etc.) of a file that I know that exists in some folder.
I know that the file name(prefix) is unique in this folder. 
The language is c++.

thanks

Comment: "The file name (prefix) is singular" - what does that mean?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Perhaps its unique?

Comment: See [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/libs/filesystem/).

Comment: It means that there is no another file in this name, e.g. file.txt and file.doc

Comment: If you have some list of known / supported formats you can just iterate and check if file is exists.

Comment: Did you mean file extension? for example, foo.png, you can get: `.png`, right?

Comment: Do you have the whole filename including the extension? Or do you only have the prefix? If you have "foo.txt" then you can compute the extension, but if you only have "foo" then it will be harder because you have to look in the directory to see what matching files exist.

Comment: I only have the prefix XXX and I wanne find yyy of XXX.yyy lol..

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that "suffix" is the filename extension, you can do this:

```
char * getfilextension(char * fullfilename)
{
   int size, index;
   size = index = 0;

   while(fullfilename[size] != '\0') {
      if(fullfilename[size] == '.') {
         index = size;
      }
       size ++; 
   }

   if(size && index) {
      return fullfilename + index;
   }
      return NULL;
}
```

It's C code, but I believe that can easily ported to C++(maybe no changes).

```
getfilextension("foo.png"); /* output -> .png */
```

I hope this help you.

**UPDATE:**

You will need scan all files of directory and compare each file without extension if is equal to your target.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <limits.h>
    #include <dirent.h>
    #include <string.h>

    //.....

    char * substr(char * string, int start, int end)
    {
       char * p = &string[start];
       char * buf = malloc(strlen(p) + 1);
       char * ptr = buf;
       if(!buf) return NULL;

       while(*p != '\0' && start < end) {
          *ptr ++ = *p++;
          start ++;
       }

       *ptr++ = '\0';

       return buf;

    }

    char * getfilenamewithoutextension(char * fullfilename)
    {
       int i, size;
       i = size = 0;

       while(fullfilename[i] != '\0') {
          if(fullfilename[i] == '.') {
             size = i;
          }

          i ++;
       }

       return substr(fullfilename, 0, size);
    }

    char * getfilextension(char * fullfilename)
    {
       int size, index;
       size = index = 0;

       while(size ++, fullfilename[size]) {
          if(fullfilename[size] == '.') {
             index = size;
          }
       }

       if(size && index) {
          return fullfilename + index;
       }
          return NULL;
    }

   char*FILE_NAME;
   int filefilter(const struct dirent * d)
   {
      return strcmp(getfilenamewithoutextension((char*)d->d_name), FILE_NAME) == 0;
   }
```

and then:

```
   void foo(char * path, char * target)  {
   FILE_NAME = target;
   struct dirent ** namelist;
   size_t dirscount;
   dirscount = scandir(path, &namelist, filefilter, alphasort);

   if(dirscount > 0) {
      int c;
      for(c = 0; c < dirscount; c++) {
            printf("Found  %s filename,the extension is %s.\n", target, getfilextension(namelist[c]->d_name));
            free(namelist[c]);
      }

      free(namelist);
   } else {
      printf("No files found on %s\n", path);
   }
```

}

and main code:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

   foo(".", "a"); /* The .(dot) scan the current path */
}
```

For a directory with this files:

```
a.c  a.c~  a.out
a.o  makefile test.cs
```

The output is:

```
Found  a filename,the extension is .c.
Found  a filename,the extension is .c~.
Found  a filename,the extension is .o.
Found  a filename,the extension is .out.
```

Note: the [`scandir()`](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_275.html) function is part of GNU extensions/GNU library,if you don't have this function available on your compiler,tell me that I will write an alias for that or use [this](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/gen.subproj/scandir.c) implementation(don't forget to read the license).

Comment: thanks Jack, but the situation is that I don't have the string "fullfilename", but I only know that there is a file in the folder named X and I want to know its extension.

Comment: While this is C code that will work in C++, you could use `std::string` and probably save yourself a lot of work here.

Comment: @זאבי כהן : May be you can use this link [How can I get a list of files in a directory using C or C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c) for that

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows, use [PathFindExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard functionality to list directory contents in c++. So if you know allowed extensions in your app you can iterate through and find if file exists.

Other options are use OS specific API or use something like Boost. You can also use "ls | grep *filename" or "dir" command dump and parse the output.